# Values in try/except available after execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, try-catch

I have a question about `try/except` in python3.

I wondered if you have code like:

**#1**

```
try:
    #do something here
    var = 'some value here'

except:
    #do something if it fails
```

**#2**

```
try:
    #do something here
    newvar = var    #var from above

except:
    #do something if it fails
```

Can I use `var` from **#1** in **#2** like Im using it or is the value of `var` no longer after it goes into the **#1** `try or except` block?

Thank you

Comment: Note, you should always catch *specific* exceptions, like `except IndexError:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If the code in #1 fails while calculating the value to store into variable `var`, the assignment will never happen and `var` will be as it was before that code block. The Python documentation explicitly says that the value on the right side of the equal sign is calculated first, and when and if that calculation is done, the resulting value is then bound to the variable name that is on the left side of the equals sign. If `var` was undefined, it will still be undefined; if it was defined and had a value, it will still have that value. It will not lose its definition or its value.

So if `var` is undefined, you will get an exception in code block #2. If `var` has an old value, it will still have it and that's what will be used on code block #2.

Whether or not that is what you want depends on other factors.

As @Chris_Rands points out in a comment, your style is not very good. You should catch specific exceptions and deal with them. Unexpected exceptions should be raised and dealt with at a higher level. The exception to this is when your code is used in a long-running program that you do not want to stop for any reason other than the user shutting it down. And in that case, you should still catch and handle the specific exception you expect, and log the unexpected ones along with their complete tracebacks into some file so that you, the programmer, can examine it later to fix the problem. Never catch all exceptions and just continue on without some kind of logging.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs in the `try` block before you have assigned your variable, it won't be declared.

In order to safely use your variable later, you also have to set it in the event of an exception (ie in your `except` block).